# Can I get commenting permission?

Tags: support, reputation, new-users, privileges

I know I don't have much rep on Super User, but I have on Ask Ubuntu.

I found a post, *[Windows 10 Audio Headset Detection Issues](https://superuser.com/questions/1077864/windows-10-audio-headset-detection-issues?rq=1)*.
And I have some potential solutions for it. Can I get permission or some other way to contact the asker? I had and have a similar issue with drivers, and I can maybe help him. Or is there a way to "make rep fast"?
My issue: *[Keep laptop sound device from shutting down after some time of standby](https://superuser.com/questions/1222633/keep-laptop-sound-device-from-shutting-down-after-some-time-of-standby)*

Comment: Please don't use that post as a dup-target, @Robert - there's almost always a more specific, more *useful* question here.

Comment: @Ramhound That's not true at all.  Providing an answer may not be helpful to the author, but it can be helpful to anyone else who has the same problem and finds the question.  Of course, that's only true if this user's answer is of higher quality than the question author's answer.

Comment: you don't need to waste your time editing or answering anymore, I got it. reminds me again how awesome stack communities are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the answer to the question, then post an answer to the question, which doesn't require any reputation.

If you want to post a comment that provides some helpful information without answering the question, then you'll need to earn 50 reputation on that site; there is no other way around that.

Yes, you can earn 50 rep rather fast, just post one (or more) great answers on the site, and you can very quickly get the 5 upvotes you need to get 50 rep.